# Bundle is failing due to ruby-oci8 gem, for ruby version 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to install oci-8 gem through bundler

```
Installing ruby-oci8 2.2.9 with native extensions
        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        
            current directory: /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8
        /Users/piush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/piush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20210422-24251-1t9o27q.rb extconf.rb
        attempting to locate oracle-instantclient...
        checking load library path... 
        *** extconf.rb failed ***
        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
        need configuration options.
        
        Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=/Users/piush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
            --with-instant-client
            --without-instant-client
            --with-instant-client-dir
            --without-instant-client-dir
            --with-instant-client-include
            --without-instant-client-include=${instant-client-dir}/include
            --with-instant-client-lib
            --without-instant-client-lib=${instant-client-dir}/lib
        /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:568:in `guess_ic_dir': RuntimeError (RuntimeError)
            from /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:268:in `get'
            from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
        /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:568:in `guess_ic_dir': Set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH or
        (RuntimeError)
        OCI_DIR to point to the Instant client directory.
        
        If DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is set, the environment
        variable must be set at runtime also.
        
        If OCI_DIR is set, dependent shared library paths are checked. If the checking
        is passed, ruby-oci8 works without DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.
        
        Note: OCI_DIR should be absolute path.
        Note: DYLD_* environment variables are unavailable for security reasons on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.
            from /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:268:in `get'
            from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
          DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.
          DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.
          checking OCI_DIR...
          checking the default value of DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...
            checking /Users/piush/lib... no
            checking /usr/local/lib... no
            checking /lib... no
            checking /usr/lib... no
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Error Message:
          Set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH or
          OCI_DIR to point to the Instant client directory.
          
          If DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is set, the environment
          variable must be set at runtime also.
          
          If OCI_DIR is set, dependent shared library paths are checked. If the checking
          is passed, ruby-oci8 works without DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.
          
          Note: OCI_DIR should be absolute path.
          Note: DYLD_* environment variables are unavailable for security reasons on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.
          
        Backtrace:
          /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:568:in `guess_ic_dir'
          /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:268:in `get'
          extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
        ---------------------------------------------------
        See:
         * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-full-client.md for Oracle full client
         * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-instant-client.md for Oracle instant client
         * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-on-osx.md for OS X
         * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/report-installation-issue.md to report an issue.
        
        
        extconf failed, exit code 1
        
        Gem files will remain installed in /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9 for inspection.
        Results logged to /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/gem_make.out
        
        An error occurred while installing ruby-oci8 (2.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
        Make sure that `gem install ruby-oci8 -v '2.2.9' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
        
        In Gemfile:
          ruby-oci8
```

My Bundle install is getting failed even if I have declared all the required variables under .bash_profile file as follow:

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/piush/Documents/oracle_12c/instantclient_12_2"
#export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/piush/Documents/oracle_12c/instantclient_12_2"
#export ORACLE_HOME="/Users/piush/Documents/oracle_12c//instantclient_12_2"
#export OCI_DIR="/Users/piush/Documents/oracle_12c/instantclient_12_2"
# Add Homebrew's executable directory to the front of the PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
~
```

Eveb I Tried to install the gem separately but still no luck and getting following:

```
piush@GUVA-161114-C02Y80Y3JGH8 project % gem install ruby-oci8 -v '2.2.9' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-oci8:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8
/Users/piush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/piush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20210422-25570-10pdwc4.rb extconf.rb
attempting to locate oracle-instantclient...
checking load library path... 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/piush/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-instant-client
    --without-instant-client
    --with-instant-client-dir
    --without-instant-client-dir
    --with-instant-client-include
    --without-instant-client-include=${instant-client-dir}/include
    --with-instant-client-lib
    --without-instant-client-lib=${instant-client-dir}/lib
/Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:568:in `guess_ic_dir': RuntimeError (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:268:in `get'
    from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
/Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:568:in `guess_ic_dir': Set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH or (RuntimeError)
OCI_DIR to point to the Instant client directory.

If DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is set, the environment
variable must be set at runtime also.

If OCI_DIR is set, dependent shared library paths are checked. If the checking
is passed, ruby-oci8 works without DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.

Note: OCI_DIR should be absolute path.
Note: DYLD_* environment variables are unavailable for security reasons on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.
    from /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:268:in `get'
    from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.
  DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.
  checking OCI_DIR...
  checking the default value of DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...
    checking /Users/piush/lib... no
    checking /usr/local/lib... no
    checking /lib... no
    checking /usr/lib... no
---------------------------------------------------
Error Message:
  Set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH or
  OCI_DIR to point to the Instant client directory.
  
  If DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is set, the environment
  variable must be set at runtime also.
  
  If OCI_DIR is set, dependent shared library paths are checked. If the checking
  is passed, ruby-oci8 works without DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.
  
  Note: OCI_DIR should be absolute path.
  Note: DYLD_* environment variables are unavailable for security reasons on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.
  
Backtrace:
  /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:568:in `guess_ic_dir'
  /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:268:in `get'
  extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------------
See:
 * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-full-client.md for Oracle full client
 * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-instant-client.md for Oracle instant client
 * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-on-osx.md for OS X
 * http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/report-installation-issue.md to report an issue.


extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/piush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/ruby-oci8-2.2.9/gem_make.out
```

Any quick help would be great as I am stuck here. The ruby version that I am using is 2.7.1

Comment: Do any of the suggestions in this issue help? https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8/issues/163

Comment: thanks @JakeWorth, but given link is not useful for me as I am not using "sudo" command.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Could you post the error message when `OCI_DIR` is set? As for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it is unset inside of subshells. The `gem` command is a shell script, so ruby-oci8 gem cannot see `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on compilation.

Comment: @KuboTakehiro Error is same as above, even i am using                                       
 export OCI_DIR="/Users/piush/Documents/oracle_12c/instantclient_12_2"

Comment: @PiyushGupta Could you check the next line of `checking OCI_DIR...`?  Is it `checking the default value of DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...` even when `OCI_DIR` is set?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Discovered the problem was because I'd only installed 2 of the 3 Oracle zip files needed.

I had installed:

- instantclient-basic-macos.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip
- instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip

When I installed instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip, I was finally able to successfully run:

`gem install ruby-oci8 -v '2.2.9'`

Info here:
https://coderwall.com/p/nvva7a/setup-oracle-instant-client-and-ruby-oci8-gem-on-mac